# Regular expressions for numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How can I build a regular expression that checks that it must be a number between 0 - 999999999.

Opted for the range validator.

Comment: You wouldn't, because regular expressions are absolutely the wrong tool for this task.

Comment: so what do you recommend.. it must check that is a number .. I tried the range validator.. but it was taking letters.. although i specified Type ="Integer"

Comment: Well, your question isn't specific enough to tell us what framework you are using to validate.  If I were answering this question I would have said "use `int.TryParse()` and check the result" but I don't even know if that's an option.  Please include more detail in your question.

Comment: @user710502 use the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) like you wanted to, just read the docs.

Comment: So?  You can call `int.TryParse()` from C# and ASP.NET, but the comments you have posted *after* asking your question lead me to believe that this would not be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean control the number which range, can use [`rangevalidator`](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_rangevalidator.asp)

```
MaximumValue    Specifies the maximum value of the input control
MinimumValue    Specifies the minimum value of the input control

<asp:RangeValidator
ControlToValidate="tbox1"
MinimumValue="1"
MaximumValue="999999999"
Type="Number"
EnableClientScript="false"
runat="server" />
```

Comment: I am using c# i forgot to add the control to the container :( thanks

Answer (score 5):

The simplest thing would be `[0-9]{1,9}` That will accept all integers between 0 - 999999999.
If you want decimals or scientific notation, that can be done too though it's trickier and you might also want to look into some other tool to validate the number *value*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you would want to match numbers that don't start with zero:

Then `[1-9]\d{0,8}` should do it.

Comment: @cdhowie , Actually I meant to say `[1-9]\d{0,8}`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
\d{1,9}
```

- `\d` - digit
- `{1,9}` - 1 to 9 repetitions

Comment: `{1-9}` is not valid regex; you mean `{1,9}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to validate this inside a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` then you need to do the same as has been hinted at so far in this thread but you also need a ^ and $ on each end so that it doesnt allow other characters to be added in around it.

```
^\d{1,9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[0-9]*
```

It works for me.

Comment: That would also work on an empty string, and on values that exceed the desired string length specified.